# Improve rendering performance of react kendo datagrid

Tags: reactjs, performance, datagrid, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I have a react-kendo datagrid and its cells are selectable. There are 385 rows and each row has 4 Selectable cells.

The problem is; When any of the checkboxes is checked, the whole grid is rerender. Accordingly, it takes about 3 seconds to be checked. Is it possible to regenerate only the edited cell?

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setScopes } from "../../redux/actions/scopeActions";

import {
  Grid,
  GridColumn as Column,
  GridToolbar,
} from "@progress/kendo-react-grid";
import { filterBy } from "@progress/kendo-data-query";
import "@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

function NewApiScopesTable({ scopes }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(scopes);

  //   const [filter, setFilter] = useState();
  //   const filterChange = (event) => {
  //     setData(filterBy(scopes, event.filter));
  //     setFilter(event.filter);
  //   };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRows(scopes);
  }, [scopes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedRows = rows.filter(
      (row) => !!row.get || !!row.post || !!row.put || !!row.delete
    );
    dispatch(setScopes(selectedRows));
  }, [rows]);

  const handleSelect = (row) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    const index = newRows.findIndex((r) => r.id === row.id);
    newRows[index] = { ...row };
    setRows(newRows);
  };

  const getCell = (props) => {
    return (
      <td>
        <Checkbox
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
          checked={props.dataItem.get}
          onChange={() =>
            handleSelect({ ...props.dataItem, get: !props.dataItem.get })
          }
        />
      </td>
    );
  };

  const postCell = (props) => {
    if (!props.dataItem.isPostEnable) {
      return <td></td>;
    } else {
      return (
        <td>
          <Checkbox
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
            checked={props.dataItem.post}
            onChange={() =>
              handleSelect({ ...props.dataItem, post: !props.dataItem.post })
            }
          />
        </td>
      );
    }
  };
  const putCell = (props) => {
    if (!props.dataItem.isPutEnable) {
      return <td></td>;
    } else {
      return (
        <td>
          <Checkbox
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
            checked={props.dataItem.put}
            onChange={() =>
              handleSelect({ ...props.dataItem, put: !props.dataItem.put })
            }
          />
        </td>
      );
    }
  };
  const deleteCell = (props) => {
    if (!props.dataItem.isDeleteEnable) {
      return <td></td>;
    } else {
      return (
        <td>
          <Checkbox
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
            checked={props.dataItem.delete}
            onChange={() =>
              handleSelect({
                ...props.dataItem,
                delete: !props.dataItem.delete,
              })
            }
          />
        </td>
      );
    }
  };


  console.log("run");
  return (
    <Grid
      style={{
        height: "500px",
      }}
      data={rows}
      //   filter={filter}
      //   onFilterChange={filterChange}
    >
      <GridToolbar>
        <input type="search" id="site-search" name="q" onChange />
      </GridToolbar>
      <Column field="name" title="Endpoint Name" width="400px" />
      <Column field="get" title="GET" cell={getCell} />
      <Column field="post" title="POST" cell={postCell} />
      <Column field="put" title="PUT" cell={putCell} />
      <Column field="delete" title="DELETE" cell={deleteCell} />
    </Grid>
  );
}

export const MemoizedNewApiScopesTable = React.memo(NewApiScopesTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for anyone stumbling upon this later, what worked for me was to memoize any custom cells. (not sure if this will fix your particular performance issue or now but it should help)

```
  const handleSelect = useCallback((row) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    const index = newRows.findIndex((r) => r.id === row.id);
    newRows[index] = { ...row };
    setRows(newRows);
  }, [//dependencies here]);

  const getCell = useMemo((props) => {
    return (
      <td>
        <Checkbox
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
          checked={props.dataItem.get}
          onChange={() =>
            handleSelect({ ...props.dataItem, get: !props.dataItem.get })
          }
        />
      </td>
    );
  },[handleSelect, props.dataItem]);
```

Notice the useMemo and useCallback hooks added. (apply any dependencies to make the linter happy, I only added a few)

The useCallback is needed on any function you put in the dependency array of useMemo, otherwise it will run every render.

Follow this patter for all custom cells and see if it helps performance.